# Loop through form inputs and build a xml string

Tags: jquery

I am trying to loop through a form and build an xml string that combines three inputs into in xml node. Very frustrated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#new-document-button", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var title = $( "#new-document-title" ).val();
        var date = $( "#new-document-date" ).val();
        var xmlData;

        var xmlTitle = '<title>' + title + '</title>';
        var xmlDate = '<date>' + date + '</date>';

        $('form#new-document-form').find('input').each(function(i, input){
            var xmlLabel = $(this).val();
            var xmlChart = $(this).attr("checked");
            var xmlValue = $(this).text();

            xmlData += '<' + xmlLabel + ' chart="' + xmlChart + '">' + xmlValue + '</' + xmlLabel + '>';

            alert(xmlData);
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asahart/j198uu1L/

Comment: To catch click event I recommend `$("#new-document-button").click(function (event) {...});`, also there are no elements as `#new-document-title`, `#new-document-date` and `ol#new-document-criteria`. Please update your code with correct HTML, so we can better respond to you.

Comment: What is the actual question please?

Comment: I have updated the code. The question is "How do I combine the value from one input with the checkbox status from another input with the value of another inputs so as to get an xml string such as:  <xmlLabel chart="xmlChart">xmlValue</xmlLabel>